# Wordpress description of parent menu in sub-menu

Tags: wordpress, menu, parent, submenu, field-description

I'm trying show the description of parent menu in submenu.

I have something like that

```
<nav>
<ul nav-menu>
<li><a>item 1</a></li>
<li><a>item 2</a>
   <div class="dropdown">
   <span> $DESCRITPION_OF_ITEM_2</span>
   <ul sub-menu>
     <li>..</li>
     <li>..</li>
   <ul>
   </div>
</ul>
</nav>
```

I need showing this variable "$DESCRITPION_OF_ITEM_2" which showing the description from menu editor in wordpress, is it possible ?

And second question, do you know good plugins or something for adding image to menu ?

Thank;s for response

Comment: I don't suppose that link helped you at all did it? As I'm trying to do the same as you, and nowhere has the answer. That link didn't help me. All I'm able to do is add the description right underneath the parent menu labels, and not inside the submenu. Did you have any luck?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this might be what you are looking for](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-show-the-description-of-the-menu).